# Databricks- Move data from Databricks temp to DataWarehouse or move from Databricks Table to Dataware house directly

Tags: data-warehouse, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

How do we move data from databricks temp view or table to dataware house directly . Please let me know
as I am new to databricks.

The document just shows direct connectivity to Datawarehouse but how do we move data

Answer (score 1):

You move data by writing a Data Frame to an external location.  EG

```
df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>")
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "my_table_in_dw_copy")
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
  .save()
```

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html

Comment: Is the table here mentiones the databricks table

Comment: df is a Data Frame.  It could be any Datacricks table, external table or query.